# Control timer in form 1 from form 2, C#

Tags: c#, timer, multiple-forms

A label in form is displaying the count of timer. Now i want to stop,start and reset it using form 2. How can i do this.plz help

Comment: Pass the Form1 reference to Form2 and call it as a property. myForm1.Timer.Reset(). How are the forms related to each other (like, 1 call 2 or whatever)?

Comment: i tried that but its not working. Form 1 calls form 2

Answer (score 3):

Forms are just classes, and the timer on Form 2 is an object inside that class.

You can change the `Modifiers` property of your timer to public, and then instantiate Form 2 inside Form 1, call the `Show()` method of Form 2, and then access your timer object which is now public.

So you have a project with 2 forms like so:

[image: Solution Explorer]

Create a button in Form 1 like so:

[image: Form One]

Place a timer object on Form 2 and change the access modifier like so:

[image: Properties]

Then put the following code under your button in form one:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    f2.timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Now you can launch form 2 and access all of the properties on the timer on form 2 from form 1.

Does this help?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot the modifiers. They are protected by default, right? +1

Answer (score 2):

If the timer object resides in Form1, then create a public property for it:

```
public Timer Form1Timer { get { return timer1; } }
```

Then you can access this timer by having a reference to Form 1 in Form 2. You can do this by passing it in to the constructor, or having a set property on Form2. Once you have a reference to Form1, you can simply call methods on the timer:

```
Form1.Form1Timer.Start();
```

You can always create a singleton out of Form1 if you cannot pass a reference of it to Form2.

Declare your singleton:

```
private static Form1 _singleton
```

Initialize your singleton if it isnt already, and return it:

```
 public static Form1 Singleton
 { 
    get { _singleton ?? (_singleton = new Form1()); } 
 }
```

For best practices, make your Form1 constructor private. This of course will not work if Form1 does not have a default constructor (parameterless).

Then in Form2:

```
Form1.Singleton.Form1Timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
static Form1 _frmObj;
public static Form1 frmObj
{
     get { return _frmObj; }
     set { _frmObj = value; }
}
```

### On Form load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      frmObj= this;
}
```

### Access form and it's controls from another form

```
Form1.frmObj.timer1.Stop();
```